# DAX / Xetra on alphavantage

Tags: stocks, ticker

I am very very happy with Alphavantage.
BUT I can't find the german stocks (Xetra)

I have tried:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=xtr:lin&apikey=MYKEY
(But this works https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=NYSE:DIN&apikey=MYKEY)

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=Lin.be&apikey=MYKEY
(But this works: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=Novo-b.CO&apikey=MYKEY)

So my question is - has anyone had any luck getting german stocks on Alphavanta (or another free service. Realtime is not crucial, but obviously a plus).

Comment: The DAX tag here refers a Mircosoft expression language, not what you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the "Search Endpoint" function to find german stocks on alphavantage.

Let's say you look for "BASF" you could query:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=BASF&apikey=[your API key]&datatype=csv
```

You get a list with possible matches:

```
symbol,name,type,region,marketOpen,marketClose,timezone,currency,matchScore
BASFY,BASF SE,Equity,United States,09:30,16:00,UTC-05,USD,0.8889
BFFAF,BASF SE,Equity,United States,09:30,16:00,UTC-05,USD,0.8889
BASFX,BMO Short Tax-Free Fund Class A,Mutual Fund,United States,09:30,16:00,UTC-    05,USD,0.8889
BAS.DEX,BASF SE,Equity,XETRA,08:00,20:00,UTC+02,EUR,0.7273
BAS.FRK,BASF SE,Equity,Frankfurt,08:00,20:00,UTC+02,EUR,0.7273
BASA.DEX,BASF SE,Equity,XETRA,08:00,20:00,UTC+02,EUR,0.7273
BAS.BER,BASF SE NA O.N.,Equity,Berlin,08:00,20:00,UTC+02,EUR,0.7273
BASF.NSE,BASF India Limited,Equity,India/NSE,09:15,15:30,UTC+5.5,INR,0.6000
```

See documentation: https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work with the yahoo symbols on alphavantage, at least for a few stocks (I did not check all). BASF for example works with:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=BASF.TI&apikey=MYKEY
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for XETRA (https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=BASF.DE&apikey=MYKEY)

Comment: yes, I am also very confused about that. Some symbols work for Xetra / .DE, but some will not. Currently I only get BASF working with BAS.VI (Vi - Vienna).

Answer (score 0):

The alphavantage symbols for German securities consist of the Xetra symbol + `.DE`. For example `EUNL.DE` (for [iShares MSCI World Core ETF](https://etfs24.de/snapshot?isin=IE00B4L5Y983)). You can find a list of all Xetra stocks [here](https://www.xetra.com/xetra-de/instrumente/aktien/liste-der-handelbaren-aktien).